# running java code through batch file & asp.net c# throwing exception

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, batch-file

i am getting error while executing java program from '.bat`file throws exception at Line`br.readLine()`. Its  executed fine when batch file executed manually

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at test9.main(test9.java:13)
```

bat file code:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\c\jop.txt" (
del "C:\c\jop.txt"
if exist "C:\c\test9.class" (
del "C:\c\test9.class"
)
) 

set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin
cd C:\c
javac test9.java >> jop.txt 2>&1
echo Successfully Compiled
java test9 >> jop.txt 2>&1
```

Sample Java Program:

```
import java.io.*;
public class test9
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      int a;
      float b;
      String s;
      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      s = br.readLine();
      System.out.println("You entered string "+s);
   }
}
```

it's  `s = br.readLine();` giving me Exception

C# code:(using in asp.net)

```
string str = @"C:\c\javacompiler.bat";
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = str;
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str);
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();       
myProcess.WaitForExit();
myProcess.Close();
TextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\c\jop.txt");
```

Comment: Did you enter a string on the command line like it asks you to? I don't see you passing a string into the Java program. System.in reads from stdio, i.e., the console.

Comment: i am trying to execute batch file through asp.net button click event.As i clicked on it,its showing me console window for a second ,then disapper & above error occur

Comment: The s of s = br.readLine() is null because there is no input coming into your Java code. Run the Java code from the command line and you'll see what I mean. It will ask you to "Enter a string" and wait until you enter something. The way you're running it as a batch file, when the batch file reaches the end, it exits.